# Are there any remakes of Thief 1/2 using the Thief 3 engine?

Tags: mods, thief-the-dark-project, thief-deadly-shadows, thief-gold

Since [playing the first two parts makes playing the third one a nicer experience](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/22683/88) but the graphics have aged not too little, is there any Total Conversion that allows one to play the first two parts with the newest engine?

Comment: I would have loved to know _what_ makes this question off topic and appreciate suggestions on invalidating that...

Comment: I would have voted to close as "not constructive".

Comment: @ChrisF Please feel free to vote reopen to do so ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there any Total Conversion that allows one to play the first two parts with the newest engine?

**No** there isn't.

**However** there are some patches/mods that can improve the old engine Thief 1 and 2 are using. The patches will improve some models and textures, increase the resolution and more.

[**DDfix:**](http://www.ttlg.com/forums/showthread.php?t=121449) patch (created by TimeSlip and updated by jermi) to allow Dark Engine games to run properly on modern hardware. It fixes the numerous problems introduced in modern graphics card drivers, as well as enabling 32-bit rendering to increase visual quality beyond even the original game. It also fixes fog in Windows 7 and Windows Vista, and enables support for widescreen resolutions.
In addition, menus and books/scrolls are no longer displayed in a hard-coded 640x480 resolution, but are instead displayed at the same resolution as the game, removing the annoying resolution-switching that has always plagued Thief.

DDFix also supports additional features, such as support for high-resolution override textures that can go beyond the Dark Engine's 256x256 maximum texture size, and post-processing effects such as bloom. These are now available in Thief Gold, Thief 2 and System Shock 2.

[**Thief Enhancement Pack**:](http://www.ttlg.com/forums/showthread.php?t=118999) improved models, textures ,compatible with Thief 2: The Metal Age, Thief: The Dark Project and Thief Gold.

[**NTEX high-res texture pack**:](http://www.ttlg.com/forums/showthread.php?t=119451) 136 new textures, compatible with Thief 2 only.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this works for System Shock 2 as well!